# Are the statements: $n!=O(2^n)$ and $2^n n^2=O(3^n)$ true or false?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I am trying to do this exercise:

Are the statements: a)$\space n!=O(2^n)$ and b)$\space2^nn^2=O(3^n)$ true or false?

I am trying to show that a) is false and still don't know what to say about b). This is what I've tried to do up to now:

a) I could prove by induction the inequality $n!>2^n$ for all $n \geq 4$. I am trying to deduce from here that there are no natural numbers $c$ and $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, $n! \leq c2^n$ but I couldn't do it.

b) I know that $2^n \leq 3^n$ and that $n^2 \leq 3^n$. Now, from these two inequalities, I can deduce that $2^nn^2 \leq 3^{2n}=9^n$, but I can't conclude from here that there is a constant $c$ such that $2^nn^2 \leq c3^n$ for sufficiently large $n$.

I would also like to understand intuitively for $b)$ why is it that the inequality is true, in case it is actually true, or why it is false, in case the inequality turns out to be false.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) is interesting to me. Can you think of a way to count the factors of 2 available, or estimate them with a lower bound that grows faster than $2^n$? For instance, what is the the base-2 logarithm of a number like $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6$? Can we estimate it's "two-ness" like $0+1+1+2+2+2$?

Comment: Interesting problem you brought up. For an even number $n$, there are at least $\dfrac{n}{2}$ factors of $2$ in $n!$ since there are $\dfrac{n}{2}$ even numbers between $1$ and $n$. For odd numbers, by a similar argument, there are at least $\dfrac{n-1}{2}$ factors of $2$ in $n!$. So, for all even numbers, I could express $n!=2^{\frac{n}{2}}n'$. I got stuck at this point.

Comment: If you restrict your attention for the sake of convenience to powers of 2, you can see by using the floor of the base-2 log on each term that there are 2 ones, 4 twos, 8 threes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the **first part**,
you can go by doing something like this.

You can get power of prime $x$ in $n!$ by $F(x,n)=\sum \lfloor \frac {n}{x^i} \rfloor$, where $F(x,n)$ is power of $x$ in $n!$. This is called **[Legendre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)**.

Now express $n!$ as product of prime powers , $n=\prod i^{F(i,n)}$ where $i$ is a prime. This representation is called **[De Polignac's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_formula)**.

Even if we assume that we can eliminate $2^n$ from $n!$, $\frac {n!}{2^n}$ will still remain a function of $n$ as there are other prime powers which are function of $n$. So you can easily  prove that there are no such $c$ and $n_0$.

For **second part**, express $3^n$ = $(1 + 2)^n$.

So we can say using [**Binomial expansion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) that,

$3^n= \frac{n^2\cdot2^n}{8}$ + some positive number (**part of third term** in binomial expansion + some positive number)

Clearly, without that other positive number,

$n^2\cdot2^n < 8\cdot3^n.$ So $n^2\cdot2^n$  is O($3^n$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am having some difficulty trying to understand how did you get from the binomial expansion $\sum_{i=0}^n \dbinom {n} {i}2^{n-i}$ to an expression of the form $\frac{n^2*2^n}{8}$+some positive number (also such that this number doesn't depend on n), could you explain me that part?, I could follow the rest.

Comment: Look for term at i=2 .

Comment: it is $\frac {n*(n-1)*2^{(n-2)}}{2}$

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)

Comment: Would you mind being a little more clear with your product notation? You're doing a product over all $i$ which are prime, and how exactly?

Comment: @Justin sure . thanks, did it. it should be prime powers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use induction or inequalities. It is enough to use the definition of $O()$.

For a: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!}{2^n} = \infty$ (obviously). Thus, it is false.

For b: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2^n n^2}{3^n} = 0$ (obvious). Also this is false.

Comment: For part b, the conclusion should be "true," not "false."  More, in fact, is true:  $2^nn^2=o(3^n)$.

Comment: @peterh could you help me to prove that those limits are $\infty$ and $0$ respectively?. Barry is right, if the limit in b) is $0$, then the statement is true.